# How to launch macro from a cell value

Tags: excel, vba

is it possible to launch a macro from the value on a cell ?
In other word I want to convert that:

```
Sub Batch()

'Execute les macros BatchRbk,BatchR, BatchAbk et BatchA à differentes heures
Application.OnTime TimeValue("08:33:00"), "Batch.BatchRbk"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("08:37:00"), "Batch.BatchR"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("10:29:00"), "Batch.BatchAbk"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("10:34:00"), "Batch.BatchA"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("10:39:00"), "Batch.BatchRbk"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("10:43:00"), "Batch.BatchR"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("11:29:00"), "Batch.BatchAbk"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("11:32:00"), "Batch.BatchA"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("12:29:00"), "Batch.BatchAbk"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("12:34:00"), "Batch.BatchA"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("13:29:00"), "Batch.BatchAbk"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("13:32:00"), "Batch.BatchA"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("13:39:00"), "Batch.BatchRbk"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("13:44:00"), "Batch.BatchR"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("14:14:00"), "Batch.BatchAbk"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("14:16:00"), "Batch.BatchA"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("14:30:00"), "Batch.BatchAbk"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("14:32:00"), "Batch.BatchA"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("14:40:00"), "Batch.BatchAbk"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("14:43:00"), "Batch.BatchA"

End Sub
```

To that:

[image]

I a way that the user can setup himself that at hour "x" he wants to launch macro "y".
Tell me if something is not clear enough, I'll rexplain it better.
Thanks !

Comment: You will be able to do it if in the E:E column there will be the necessary subs name. But what you show us looks incorrect. A sub cannot be named with spaces in the name... Then, if the `Sub` is not private at the module level, no need to write the module name, too. If you want to make it clearer for the user you should write as you tried, but somewhere else in the same row (maybe in a hidden column) the correct function name must be placed.

Comment: Edited ! I prefer to write the name module 'cause I have two modules in this wb, so i'd rather leave it just in case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, try the next way:

1. Besides the data you show us in columns "D:E", you need another column with the real name of the `Sub` to be called ("Batch.BatchRbk", "Batch.BatchR" etc.). Let us put it in the F:F column, which may be hidden, or not.
2. Then proceed in the next way:

```
Sub Batch()
 Dim ws as Worksheet,lastR as Long, i as long

 Set ws = ActiveSheet  
 lastR = ws.Range("D" & ws.rows.count).End(xlup).row
 For i = 2 to lastR
    Application.OnTime TimeValue(ws.Range("D" & i).value), ws.Range("F" & i).value
 Next i
End Sub
```

In F:F column you must place: "Batch.BatchRbk", "Batch.BatchR", "Batch.BatchAbk" and so on...